# docker-compose / mysql / increasing max connections

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that creates a mysql server and then runs python script which pushes data into that docker mysql server. However, when the mysql server is created it takes the default 150 max connections. How can I amend the docker-compose file below, so that max connections is increased to 10000?

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=high_frequency
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX
    ports:
      - '3311:3311'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  hf_run:
    container_name: hf_run
    build: .
    command: ./main.py -r run_docker
    restart: on-failure:50
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 81:81
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: XXX
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: XXX
      DB_NAME: high_frequency
    links:
      - db
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can increase max connections on launch of database in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    command: [ "--max_connections=1000" ]
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=high_frequency
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX
    ports:
      - '3311:3311'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  hf_run:
    container_name: hf_run
    build: .
    command: ./main.py -r run_docker
    restart: on-failure:50
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 81:81
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: XXX
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: XXX
      DB_NAME: high_frequency
    links:
      - db
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).